# Android bluetooth touchpad emulation

Tags: android, bluetooth, mouse, emulation, touchpad

I was thinking about the possibility to use my Android device as a touchpad with usual computers (without the need of special software on the computer's side).

Do you think it's possible to identify the android phone as a bluetooth mouse against a computer? Do I need to root my phone or does the Android SDK/bluetooth stack allows me something like that?

I'm knew to this topic. Does anybody can provide me some useful links / information ?

Answer (score 5):

http://code.google.com/p/android-bluetooth-touchpad/

This is exactly what I have done. It is my bachelor thesis. You need a rooted phone and Linux on the computer side. You do not have to install anything on your computer. It uses the HID class drivers.

Answer (score 1):

You will need is Bluetooth HID profile support on the android phone, and also for the phone to act as a HID device i.e support the Bluetooth HID device role.

HID is officially supported in honeycomb. See this - [Android Bluetooth Features](http://source.android.com/porting/bluetooth.html)
I think the current support is only for HID host role , i.e. for keyboards / mice etc to connect with and input to the phone.

Also currently there are no APIs exposed for applications to access.

Answer (score 1):

Check this app [Serverless Bluetooth Keyboard & Mouse for PC/Phone](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.appground.blek) and the related introduction post [How to Use Your Android Phone as a Bluetooth Mouse or Keyboard](https://www.howtogeek.com/714170/how-to-use-your-android-phone-as-a-bluetooth-mouse-or-keyboard/)

Comment: No source code though…

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done, it is often referred to as [HID over GATT](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/hid-over-gatt-profile-1-0/).
There is at least [one app on the Play Store that does that](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.appground.blek). No root needed, no software on the PC side to install.
I could find two GitHub repositories implementing such solutions:

- [BLE-HID-Peripheral-for-Android](https://github.com/kshoji/BLE-HID-Peripheral-for-Android)
- [BLE_HID_Example](https://github.com/Aleksander-Drewnicki/BLE_HID_EXAMPLE)

Though neither of them have been maintained in years so it is fair to assume they won't compile and work out of the box.